# Laravel get specific page programmatically

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination, laravel

I am trying to implement pagination with Laravel and jQuery ajax.

I need to send page number to a post controller and get the results for that specific page.

So my question is. Is there a way to get a specific page from the Paginator in Laravel, something like `$model->page(3)` for getting the third page from the paginated data as an array, so i can serialize it as JSON and send back as a response?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the good people on Laravel's irc channel I found the answer. So i will write here as help for others. The magic is this:

`Input::merge(array("page" => $page_number))`

you actually make Laravel's Paginator thinks that a "page" parameter is passed in the action. Neat huh :)

Comment: you really should post your update as an answer to the question. This will help the community, as it's will mark you question as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the good people on Laravel's irc channel I found the answer. So i will write here as help for others. The magic is this:

```
Input::merge(array("page" => $page_number))
```

you actually make Laravel's Paginator thinks that a "page" parameter is passed in the action. Neat huh :)

Answer (score 0):

To follow up, you need to start your route to get. Like:
Route::get('...');

If Route with post, like Route::post('...');    this not working.

djandreski thank you so much for this solution, I hope it will help others.